# Strange behaviour while adding string to another string in C++

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

`one` is `2`, and `ans` is `"000000"`.

```
string ans = "000000";
ans += string("1", one);
cout<<ans<<endl;
```

The output is:

`0000001�`

But I want the output:

`00000011`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The output should be `0000011` not the strange `?` character that appears at the end of the string.

Comment: "4) Constructs the string with the first count characters of character string pointed to by s. s can contain null characters. The length of the string is count. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + count) is not a valid range." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi That's not a question. That's a statement. And the statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string("1", one)` does not do what you think it does.  It does not duplicate the `"1"` string `one` number of times.  It instead copies the 1st `one` number of `char`s from `"1"`, which in this case is the `'1'` character and the `'\0'` null-terminator that follows it, which is where the `�` is coming from in the output.  That is not what you want.

Use `string(one, '1')` instead.  That will duplicate the `'1'` character `one` number of times, like you want, eg:

```cpp
ans = "000000";
ans += string(one, '1');
cout << ans << endl;
```

Comment: what if someone want to append "11" two times? string(2, "12") does not work then. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Shantanu `string(4, '1')`

Comment: @JohnFilleau in that case, using `string(one*2, '1')` would make more sense for this situation.

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi There is no `string` constructor to duplicate a multi-character string N times, only a single `char` N times. You can use that constructor the way John shows, or you can use a manual loop instead, eg: `for(int i = 0; i < one; ++i) { ans += "11"; }`

Answer (score -1):

Just use c++ strings and use `+` operator to catenate strings.

Comment: Pretty sure that's what the asker is trying to do with `string("1", one);`. They just got the arguments wrong.